# Schengen visa travel to other countries

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen

I just received my Schengen visa to visit France with multiple entries. I want to travel to Czech Republic after visiting France and I was wondering if I have to produce hotel reservations and return plane tickets at the Czech border control?
As I have never been to Europe before I don't know how Schengen visa works.

Comment: There are no border controls between Schengen countries, at least in theory.

Comment: The Czech border control may ask you for these things before letting you in, but as @blackbird57 notes, if you travel directly from another Schengen country, you will most likely not encounter the Czech border control.  Your best bet is to be prepared to show these, so you can be happy if you don't have to, but not sad if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "ETATS SCHENGEN" appears at the top of your visa, then you may travel to any of the 25 (or is it 26 now)? Schengen countries from any other, without passing through regular formal border controls. You won't normally need to provide any extra evidence.

Note that in unusual situations (such as the current refugee crisis) there may be immigration controls in unusual places, but on your itinerary you are unlikely to see these, and if you do, they will look for your visa and entry stamp, note your status is valid, and most likely pass you right through.